# WPF 4 Ribbon Window Bar Region not highlighting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In Microsoft Word, when you placed the mouse over the ribbon bar, the square region will be highlighted.

However, the highlighting is not showing up in my ribbon bar. I am new to WPF, please can someone point to me where to look for in the xaml code

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do like this. Highlighting with slight animation in XAML.

In `<Window.Resources>` define `Style`:

`<Style x:Key="RectStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                  To="#FF008CFF" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                  To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>`

Then in definition of some Rectangle(button or what you want) you must mention your `Style`:

`<Rectangle x:Name="rect_abortTrans" Style="{StaticResource RectStyle}" ... >`

That's it. The square region will be highlighted on `MouseOver`.
Also, you can look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/90238291-5279-43cf-be75-05e1156a1165/how-to-fill-the-color-of-the-button-in-mouse-over-using-xaml-itself?forum=silverlightnet).